# How do I add a column of incrementing values to cmdlet output?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Suppose I call [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-5.1) and want to assign a new column `ID` with the cmdlet output that prints incrementing integers so that:

```
ID  Status Name                            DisplayName
--  ------ ----                            -----------
 0 Running AdobeARMservice                 Adobe Acrobat Update Service
 1 Stopped AeLookupSvc                     Application Experience
 2 Stopped ALG                             Application Layer Gateway Service
```

I'm trying to use [`Select-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) right now to add this column, but I don't quite understand how to iterate a variable in this sort of expression.  Here's what I've got:

```
Get-Service |
Select-Object @{ Name = "ID" ; Expression= {  } }, Status, Name, DisplayName |
Format-Table -Autosize
```

Is there a way to iterate integers within `Expression= {  }`, or am I going about this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it this way, though you will need to maintain some counter variable outside of the main expression.

```
$counter = 0
Get-Service |
Select-Object @{ Name = "ID" ; Expression= {$global:counter; $global:counter++} }, Status, Name, DisplayName |
Format-Table -Autosize
```

Another option, which is perhaps cleaner

```
Get-Service `
|% {$counter = -1} {$counter++; $_ | Add-Member -Name ID -Value $counter -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru} `
| Format-Table ID
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked the [same question a different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348948/is-it-possible-to-increment-a-powershell-pipe-variable/44355109#44355109) and got the following answer

```
$x = 10
Get-Service |
Select-Object @{ Name = "ID" ; Expression={ (([ref]$x).Value++) }}, Status, Name, DisplayName | Format-Table -Autosize
```

It wasn't at all clear to me that the expression is being invoked within Select-Object's scope, not the pipe's.  The **[ref]** qualifier bumps the increment's result up to the pipe's scope achieving the same result as explicitly specifying the variable as global.

Comment: I like this solution much better than explicitly naming a scope.  Using Global isn't usually a good thing to do in most cases and other scopes are not always so easily referred to explicitly.
This 'trick' does pose a danger in that it will modify the first variable it finds as it walks thru accessible scopes but as long as you know it can't somehow grab one in the wrong scope it's quite elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This function keeps your code clean:

$table | Add-Increment -label "MyIndex"

```
function Add-Increment([string]$label="Index") {
  begin {
    $index = 0
  }
  process {

    $_ | select @{l=$label; e={ $index }}, *
    $index++ | Out-Null    
  }
}
```