# Is it possible to increment a PowerShell pipe variable?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to count a record as it passes through a pipe. My expression looks like:

```
$x=28 
gci | Select-Object basename, fullname, @{name='x'; Expression={($x--)}}
```

I get:

```
BaseName FullName                x
-------- --------                -
aaoeu    C:\Users\m\x\aaoeu.txt 28
aue      C:\Users\m\x\aue.txt   28
xx       C:\Users\m\x\xx.txt    28
```

I've tried [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Member) instead of the @ expression as above and that did the same thing - x doesn't alter value per object.

My end-goal is to generate a CSV file so I could use Write-Host to iterate through the Get-ChildItem (gci) output if it's not possible to get my variables to change value as gci emits records.

Am I missing the correct syntax to increment a variable in Select-Object or Add-Member or is it just not possible to do that?

Comment: `Expression={ (([ref]$x).Value--) }`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks! That worked though it's not clear to me what's going on. I think of "by ref" calls when I want operations in a subroutine to affect a variable that's global to the subroutine. I'm not seeing where the "subroutine" boundaries are in this instance.

Comment: `Select-Object` invoke `Expression` in separate scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 2 (with a global variable):

```
$global:x=28 
Get-ChildItem | select-object basename,fullname,@{name='x'; Expression={($global:x--)}}
```

Short version:

```
$global:x=28 
gci | select basename,fullname,@{N='x'; E={($global:x--)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 (foreach can found variable):

```
$x=28 
gci | %{ $x++; [pscustomobject]@{BaseName=$_.BaseName; FullName=$_.FullName; x=$x}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3 (declaration into the loop):

```
gci | foreach -Begin {$x=28 } -process { $x++; [pscustomobject]@{BaseName=$_.BaseName; FullName=$_.FullName; x=$x}}
```